# Implement queue using push & pop operation of stack

Tags: algorithm, stack, queue

While searching on the internet I found many answers for **How to implement a queue using 2 stacks?**
But How can I implement a queue using only push and pop operations of a stack. The **push** operation of stack can be used in a similar way as **enqueue** operation of a queue as both appends the data at the end. But the problem lies in implementing **deque** operation as queue works in a FIFO manner while stack in a LIFO manner.
I know somewhere we will have to use recursion as in case of reversing a stack using only push and pop operations of stack.
The pseudocode which I am writing for reversing the stack using **push(),pop() & isEmptyStack()** functions of a stack is

```
void reverseStack(Stack s){
if(isEmptyStack(s))
return

temp=pop(s)
reverseStack(s)
push(s,temp)
}
```

Comment: LMGTFY : http://allaboutalgorithms.wordpress.com/2011/10/24/implement-queue-with-a-single-stack/

Comment: Easy.  You Cheat.  Use the call stack as your second stack.  Also known as recursion.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to do it without recursion.

1)Let's maintain two stacks s1 and s2(both are initially empty).

2)enqueue: push to stack s1.

3)deque: if s2 is empty, while s1 is not empty pop elements from s1 and push them to s2.
Return pop(s2).

This solution has O(n) time complexity(for n queries) because each element is pushed only twice(to s1 and s2) and popped only twice.

Answer (score -1):

We don't have to use recursion.
in fact, implementing queue using two stacks is not hard.

But here we can use only standard operations of a stack -- which means only push to back, peek/pop from front, size, and is empty operations are valid.

Two stacks are needed:we can name them input and output separately.
Input is used to push every element into a simulated queue(your target).
When you want to pop elements from the simulated queue, or get the front of the queue. You should check if the output stack is empty, if output is empty, you should pop all elements from input stack into output.
Then the previous first element in input is now at the top of output stack.

C++ codes are as follows: s1 meams input stack, s2 means output stack

```
class Queue {
public:
    // Push element x to the back of queue.
    void push(int x) {
        s1.push(x);
    }

    // Removes the element from in front of queue.
    void pop(void) {
        assert(!s1.empty()||!s2.empty());
        if(!s2.empty()) s2.pop();
        else {
            while(!s1.empty()){
                int t=s1.top();
                s1.pop();
                s2.push(t);
            }
            s2.pop();
        }
    }

    // Get the front element.
    int peek(void) {
        assert(!s1.empty()||!s2.empty());
         if(!s2.empty()) {
             return s2.top();
         }
        else {
            while(!s1.empty()){
                int t=s1.top();
                s1.pop();
                s2.push(t);
            }
             return s2.top();
        }
    }

    // Return whether the queue is empty.
    bool empty(void) {
        return s1.empty()&&s2.empty();
    }
private:
    stack<int> s1;
    stack<int> s2;
};`
```

In addition,depending on your language, you may simulate a stack using list or deque.